5 duplicates, which one is the best?
There are five duplicates. Which of them should stay, which of them should be duplicates?

json-rpc api works locally but getting "Connection Refused" remotely
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = dial tcp 103.102.44.207:9735: connect: connection refused
Bitcoin RPC ECONNREFUSED
RPC connection ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8332

